# Change the Information on a Self Signed Generated Certificate

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, makecert

I have previously generated a certificate using the Visual Studio "makecert" program.

Is there any way of being able to modify the Name, Email, Address values on the certificate?

Currently the certificate has null for those values.

Answer (score 0):

If you the name of the key store, you can create a new certificate using the same RSA key pair by calling makecert with the `-sk` argument. Otherwise, you will need to create a new certificate with the correct values.